# why do I get "You are currently banned from flagging"

Tags: support, flagging

Today When I tried to flag few answers, I'm getting "You are currently banned from flagging", why do I get.?

Comment: Does [Allow recovery from flag hellban](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/180230) give any clue?